Cannot convert from '.Controllers.DeviceController' to 'System.Web.UI.Page' when trying to pass method in class library
After pressing button from controller, I need to have pass current view to method in class library. I'm trying to do it with this line :
In controller:
session.ExecuteCommand(this, doc, (response) =>
{
    CmdGetNextGlogResponse cmd_resp = new CmdGetNextGlogResponse();
    switch (cmd_resp.ParseResult(response.Xml))
    {
        case CommandExeResult.OK:
            cmd_resp.Parse(response.Xml);
             break;          
        default:
            Result = "Failed!";
            break;
    }
},
(ex) =>
{
    Result = ex.Message;
});

Class Library method is below
public void ExecuteCommand(System.Web.UI.Page page, XmlDocument request,       DeviceResponseHandler responseHandler, ExceptionHandler responseExceptionHandler)
{
    page.RegisterAsyncTask(new System.Web.UI.PageAsyncTask(
        (sender, e, cb, extraData) => BeginCommand(request,cb, extraData),
        (ar) => {
            try
            {
                using (var resp = new DeviceResponse(this, ar)) responseHandler(resp);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                responseExceptionHandler(ex); 
            }
        },
        null,//(ar) => CancelCommand(ar, new TimeoutException()),
        null));
}
   
public IAsyncResult BeginCommand(XmlDocument message, AsyncCallback cb, object extra)
{
    return BeginCommand(message, cb, extra, 5000);////Timeout.Infinite);
}
public IAsyncResult BeginCommand(XmlDocument message, AsyncCallback cb, object extra, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Async ar = new Async(cb, extra);

    if (millisecondsTimeout != Timeout.Infinite)
        ar.timeout_timer = new Timer(ar.on_timeout, this, millisecondsTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);

    CommandRequest request;
    request.message = message;
    request.ar = ar;

    lock (_state)
    {
        ar.message_id = 1;// _nextTransactionId;
        ///_nextTransactionId = (_nextTransactionId + 1) & MsgId_SequenceMask;
        _nextTransactionId = _nextTransactionId + 1;


        // Add command to wait-response queue.
        _commandsWaitingForResponses.Add(request.ar.message_id, request);

    }

    bool succeeded = false;
    try
    {
        this.Send(message.OuterXml);

        succeeded = true;
        return ar;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!succeeded)
        {
            lock (_state)
            {
                // Remove the command from wait-polling queue.
                // _commandsWaitingForResponses.Remove(request.ar.message_id);
            }

            lock (ar.monitor)
            {
                if (ar.timeout_timer != null)
                {
                    ar.timeout_timer.Dispose();
                    ar.timeout_timer = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The error is:

Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
'WebApplication2.Controllers.DevicesController' to
'System.Web.UI.Page'

I am tried  BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Default.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page for replace 'this', it enters into method but it threw some error
Asp page,cache,codebehind,contenttype threw exception
It cannot enter IAsyncResult BeginCommand method
Above works fine in asp.net web form application but in mvc we are trying not works fine.
In Asp web forms above code works fine and enter into Async method and returns data as perfect. In MVC we need replacement for 'this' or any other better solution
I've tried looking similar topics, changing 'this' to 'Page' and so on - no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

what are you trying to do? surely a control class is different from a aspx page?

You are passing this as the first parameter to your ExecuteCommand method.  But, as the error message tells you, this is a Controller and not a Page, as required by your method signature

We are upgrade asp web forms to mvc ,the problem is in class library executecommand method first parameter as System.Web.Ui.Page ,but now dont know how to pass my view or partial view to this method from controller as like similar in webforms. any help

I tried BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/Pages/TimeLogReadPane.aspx", typeof(object)) for replace this command it enters executecommand but not entering BeginCommand .

I strongly suspect, that you are going about this the wrong way.  What exactly are your "commands" doing?  I am guessing that in response to user action, you are calling an asynchronous function, and on completion want to update all or part of the view?  If this is the case, then in the MVC world, you need an async controller action that returns a partial view.  This controller action would be called by means of an ajax call, itself in response to user behaviour.  The result (the partial view) is then used to replace a section of your view.

@JonathanWillcock  im using async method only ,but the problem is for executecommand parameter page how to pass my view . I tried lot ,if it enters executecommand not enter into PageAsyncTask . I am really tired . any help

You should not be passing a view as a parameter to anything. Possibly you require the viewmodel to which the view is bound?  I would like to help you, but you are not providing any way near enough information.  What exactly do you want from the view?
ASP.Net Views and aspx pages are completely different things.  Do not try to treat them as if they were the same.

aspx pages used RegisterAsyncTask so that the page auto updated as the registered tasks progressed. Don't do it this way anymore!!!! On page load fire Ajax calls to trigger whatever long running tasks you require.  Then use the .html() function to update an empty div with whatever message you get back from your async Controller actions.

When moving from aspx to ASP.Net please don't assume that everything will translate one-to-one.  Some things are different, very different, and usually for a (very) good reason.  It can be a painful process (from experience - I have converted a very large legacy system), but I assure you, it is worth making the effort!  If you need any specific help, my email is in my profile.
